# template argument involving template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is there a way to workaround the limitations of the standard when it comes to use template parameters in template arguments in partial specialization? The code that I'd like to make it work is this:

```
template<typename L, size_t offset, typename enable_if< (offset<sizeof(L)), int >::type =0>
class a{};

template<typename L>
class a<L, sizeof(L)-1>{};
```

Comment: It is not clear from the code what you mean. Assuming that the code would compile, you are basically (if I understood it correctly) defining a template with two arguments a type and an offset, the second of which will default to `sizeof(L)-1` if not provided by the user... That's simple: `template <class T, int offset = sizeof(T)-1 > class a {};` But I understand that is not your intention. When asking you should state what you mean rather than just non-working code. And more so when you are talking about code that you know is not supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's C++11, you could simply use `static_assert` for the generic condition. For the `sizeof(L)-1` thing, you need to use the `enable_if`  trick since it requires something to  be specialized. Example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdio>

template <typename L, size_t offset, typename = void>
class a
{
    static_assert(offset < sizeof(L), "something's wrong");
public:
    void f()
    {
        printf("generic\n");
    }
};

template <typename L, size_t offset>
class a<L, offset, typename std::enable_if<offset == sizeof(L)-1>::type>
{
    // note: the static_assert is *not* inherited here.
public:
    void f()
    {
        printf("specialized\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(sizeof(int) == 4, "oops");
    a<int, 3> x;
    a<int, 2> y;
    x.f();
    y.f();
    return 0;
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/D2cs5

Comment: your code doesn't compile, in fact the true problem (`sizeof(L) - 1` in the template arguments) is still there.

Comment: Great. One more question: here, am I right to think that both the class templates match the call in the main, but the specialized version is preferred because it is, indeed, specialized?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if this is what you mean. This is how you can select a different implementation if the second template arguemnt matches the size of first template argument - 1.

```
template<typename L, size_t offset>
class aImplMatch
{   // choose this if offset == sizeof(L) - 1
    L v;
};

template<typename L, size_t offset>
class aImpl
{  
    L v;
    char off[offset];
};

template<typename L, size_t offset, size_t i>
struct SelectImpl{};

template<typename L, size_t offset>
struct SelectImpl<L, offset, 0> { typedef aImplMatch<L, offset> Result; };

template<typename L, size_t offset>
struct SelectImpl<L, offset, 1> { typedef aImpl<L, offset> Result; };

template<typename L, size_t offset>
class a
{
    enum {I = offset == sizeof(offset) - 1 ? 0 : 1 };
    typedef typename SelectImpl<L, offset, I>::Result Impl;
    Impl impl;
};
```

Maybe it could be done better / easier, this was my first thought...